# How to get value from XML file?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, discord.py

I have that xml file, and I need only to get value from `steamID64` (`76561198875082603`).

```xml
<profile>
 <steamID64>76561198875082603</steamID64>
 <steamID>...</steamID>
 <onlineState>online</onlineState>
 <stateMessage>...</stateMessage>
 <privacyState>public</privacyState>
 <visibilityState>3</visibilityState>
 <avatarIcon>...</avatarIcon>
 <avatarMedium>...</avatarMedium>
 <avatarFull>...</avatarFull>
 <vacBanned>0</vacBanned>
 <tradeBanState>None</tradeBanState>
 <isLimitedAccount>0</isLimitedAccount>
 <customURL>...</customURL>
 <memberSince>December 8, 2018</memberSince>
 <steamRating/>
 <hoursPlayed2Wk>0.0</hoursPlayed2Wk>
 <headline>...</headline>
 <location>...</location>
 <realname>
 <![CDATA[ THEMakci7m87 ]]>
 </realname>
 <summary>...</summary>
 <mostPlayedGames>...</mostPlayedGames>
 <groups>...</groups>
</profile>
```

Now I have only that code:

```
xml_url = f'{url}?xml=1'
```

then I don't know what to do.

Comment: is parsing the file and extracting the value OK? If not, why not?

Comment: Use the [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) to parse the XML data and extract the value (there's a short tutorial in the documentation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly simple with lxml:

```
import lxml.html as lh

steam = """your html above"""

doc = lh.fromstring(steam)
doc.xpath('//steamid64/text()')
```

Output:

```
['76561198875082603']
```

Edit:

With the actual url, it's clear that the underlying data is xml; so the better way to do it is:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/themakci7m87/?xml=1'

req = requests.get(url)
doc = etree.XML(req.text.encode())
doc.xpath('//steamID64/text()')
```

Same output.

Comment: but i get empty output  []

  `xml_url = f'{(url)}?xml=1'
  steam = xml_url
  doc = lh.fromstring(steam)
  output = doc.xpath('//steamID64/text()')
  await ctx.send(steam)
  await ctx.send(doc.xpath('//steamID64/text()'))
  await ctx.send(output)`

Comment: @THEMakci7m87 The problem is somewhere in `xml_url = f'{(url)}?xml=1'   steam = xml_url`. You either have to get a string and parse it with `lh.fromstring` like in the answer, or get it into a file and parse it with `lh.parse(filename)`. If you have a problem with that, you may have to post it as a separate question with the actual url you are using.

Comment: `doc = lh.fromstring(steam)` gives value = `<Element p at 0x7f655a9a7e58>`

Comment: I test `xml_url = f'{(url)}?xml=1'   steam = xml_url` there all allright, it produces a link = https://steamcommunity.com/id/themakci7m87/?xml=1, if open that you can see xml file

Answer (score -1):

You better use builtin XML lib named [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

lxml is an external XML lib that requires a separate installation.

See below

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

r = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/id/themakci7m87/?xml=1')
if r.status_code == 200:
  root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
  steam_id_64 = root.find('./steamID64').text
  print(steam_id_64)
else:
  print('Failed to read data.')
```

output:

```
76561198875082603
```